# Как вставить переменную JS в ХТМЛ?

Tags: html, переменные, javascript

```
<img src="как вставить сюда переменную джава скрипт????" name="slideshow" width=600 height=400>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KwqLm/

Answer (score 0):

Присвоить картинке class или id.

```
var img = document.getElementById('imgId');
        img.src = yourVariable;
```